# How to disable ad-blocker in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

I am using Safari running in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 for browsing the Web. I am trying to sign up to a website that requires reCAPTCHA identification. Safari has ad-blocker enabled and therefore blocks it.

How do I disable this? The web-page says:

```
(Captcha will load here (please disable Ad Blocker)
```

where the CAPTCHA is supposed to be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  given your comment this appears blocked due to  your network's administrator.

Comment: @Mark - that's not a valid close reason.  That would be *an answer* to the question being asked.

Comment: @Allan no as it is the op saying that so is part of the question and changes it significantly

Answer (score 2):

There is no ad blocker built into Safari. You most likely have a 3rd party ad-blocker extension installed.

To disable it temporarily, open Safari → Preferences, go to Extensions tab and remove the check in front of the ad-blocker extension. (You may have a different ad-blocker extension installed than shown.)

[image]

Comment: The website for reCAPTCHA is blocked. Could this be why it isn't loading? (no adblocker extensions)

Comment: Where is the website blocked? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not sure of the name of the website but I do not have access to it as administrator privileges are reprimanded and only specific sites may be allowed by higher authority. Do you happen to know the website reCAPTCHA is hosted on?

Comment: I'd advise you to seek assistance with the network administrator.